# Using ffmpeg to strip image based subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to remove *only* image based subtitles using ffmpeg? I know that you can manually select/exclude streams using -map, however I'm trying to automate this process, and the input files have a mix of image based subtitles (pgssubs) and text based subtitles. Since I'm trying to encode to an MP4 container, the image based subtitles are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot write the script but here is the idea. First get the `codec_name` of your text-based subtitle from a video

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 <test video name>
```

Now replace  with that with that codec name in te following script.

```
Usage: imgsrtremover <file name>
Output: <filename without extention>.mp4
```

```
#! /bin/bash
imgsrtstreams=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 $1 | grep -n "<codec>" | cut -f1 -d:)
cmd="ffmpeg -i $1 -map 0"
for i in $imgsrtstreams
do
cmd+=" -map -0:$((i-1))"
done 
$cmd -c copy $(echo "$1" | rev|cut -f 2- -d '.'|rev).mp4
```